# VBA to save excel tab on new file runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will export one tab to a new file then save it using a custom file name and file path based on 2 cell values.  I keep getting a runtime error during the save portion.  I've tried to use the answers on similar issues here but being the noob that i am, can't seem to get them to work for my issue.  All the help I can get is really going to be appreciated.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub Export()

    Sheets("Form").Select
    Sheets("Form").Copy
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Dim fname As String
    fname = Range("C1")
    Dim fpath As String
    fpath = Range ("G1")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & fname & ".xls"
       Windows("Form.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the value of fpath end with a backslash? if not, it should.

Comment: yes it does.  also tried it without by changing saveas syntax to this: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & "\" & fname.  additional info would be that the error shows excel cant access the file then gives the fpath value, the fname value, then a backslash with letters and numbers.  ie C:users\me\downloads\formexport\0CBC123 where 0CBC123 is the one that shouldn't be part of the name

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & fname & ".xls"` to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & fname & ".xls", FileFormat:=56`

Comment: the error is still runtime 1004 saying excel cannot access the file.

Comment: What's the exact text in the error message? e.g. `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`. Does the folder structure in `fpath` exist?

Comment: using the most recent code suggested, the exact error is "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Form. There are several possible reasons:  -The file name or path does not exist - The file name is being used by another program. - The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a (gets cut off there)

Comment: and yes, the folder structure does exist.

Comment: figured it out.  the user was entering a filename in C1 using "\".  What you gave is working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. the user was entering a value in C1 using "\". It's saving fine now.  What you gave is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Just a hint: I also got the odd filename mentioned above in the form `C:users\me\downloads\formexport\0CBC123` **where 0CBC123 is the one that shouldn't be part of the name**. It appears to use a temporary folder/file name when the expected path does not exist.